# Lost responsive while switching server

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm facing a weird issue, I had two sites on a web hosting provider (OVH), both sides were running smoothly and correctly.

I decided to get a dedicated server (for many purposes, amongst them i wanted to be fully independant concerning the configuration).
I'm using an Ubuntu based server with Caddy, sites are made out of jQuery, HTML5/Css3. Since i've put them on my dedicated server, the responsive isn't working anymore while the exact same website is still responsive on the web hosting server...

What should i look after? I don't have any idea where to begin at :s

Thanks for your help!

Comment: HTML and CSS doesn't concern what technology you are using on server. Check browser console whether all css files are accessible after switching server.

Comment: make sure all files are transfered. check error in console after opening the website

Comment: Didn't thought about checking console humpf...

Dumb error : httpS website calling http script... problem solved by correcting the script source from http:// to https://

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

Check for script calling, the sources for external files have to be the same as the website url (if website is https, file sources should be https too).